# Extracting or selecting only 4 digit numbers from attribute field

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, select-by-attribute, string, regular-expression

I have a field, this field has integer numbers, what I need is to find only the 4 digit numbers and select/extract them. I do know a few solutions but they didn’t work out. What exactly I want to do is remove the others but 4 digit numbers. How could I make it?

I use QGIS for this.

Comment: It helps to provide example data.  Although an answer has been put forward, the regex expression in it will not work unless the text field only has a 4-digit string, which I get the impression is not the case here.  Does the field in question have other content besides numbers?  Are their potentially multiple instances of numbers in the text, some being more or less than 4?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Extract by Expression`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisextractbyexpression) with regular expressions using the function [`regepx_match()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-match). Use this expression:

```
regexp_match ("number",'^\\d{4}$')
```

**Explanation:**

Match any occurence in the field `number` with this pattern:

- `^` start of string
- `\\d` a digit (0 to 9 - Backslash characters must be double escaped in QGIS)
- `{4}` 4 repetitions
- `$` end of string

**Variant: negative numbers**

If you also have negative number, use this expression to also capture negative 4 digit values:

```
regexp_match ("number",'^\\-?\\d{4}$')
```

- `\\-` a hyphen (`-`, minus sign) at the beginning, must be double escaped by `\\`
- `?` optional character: the character before the question mark is optional

[image]

Comment: Also: length("number") = 4

Comment: Does work, but only for positive values. If you have negative values, 3-digit-numbers (`-645`) will be matched. I added a variant for negative values as well. Or, based on your proposal, using abs(): `length(abs(number))=4`